# How to query withot empty rows in postgresql?

Tags: json, postgresql

So I am trying to query without empty rows for a JSON array, but doesn't seem to work. The row will not have a `null` value or `[]` on the empty rows. it will be just empty. See below for the query,

```
and d.json_id ->> 'sourcedepartmentId' <> ''
```

The query still results in empty rows. Any help on this. Thanks

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Maybe the key doesn't even exist in the JSON column, so maybe you need to check also if the result of that expression is `null` (which is something different than `''`). Or maybe you just want to test for the _presence_ of the key which is done with the `?` operator.